# Get wifi Details via the browser

Tags: android, browser, cross-browser, wifi

I am trying to implement a WiFi related application that will be used on mobile phones.

I can do these easily on android using the `WiFiManager` class where I can get the list of the WiFi Networks available around the phone, or even with the `WifiInfo` class.

However, I want to make this app more general rather and run in from a browser rather natively via android.

My question is, can I do such things using a client side scripting language that can run inside a browser that can be used literally on any phone that has a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a way of directly accessing available networks inside a browser. This is because of security reasons. The JavaScript sandbox makes sure no such information is exposed to possible malicious websites.
You could rather make some ajax request to a native app and pull needed data from there.